# Uso do ResultSet, convertendo String para Array

Tags: java, mysql, array, resultset

Estou tentando converter alguns dados que vem do BD para um Array, utilizando ResultSet para selecionar os dados do BD. No código abaixo ele não dá erro nenhum porém Se eu tentar usar um:

> System.out.println(x[0]);

Ele não mostra o primeiro dado, então parece que não foi feita a conversão, eu queria saber se é assim mesmo que converte, ou se ele não pode ser feito dentro do while.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    connection = new Conexao().getConnection();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM figura";
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            String x = rs.getString(2);
            String y = rs.getString(3);
            x.toCharArray();
            y.toCharArray();
            System.out.println(x);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está querendo montar um `Array` com 2 valores, ou 2 `Array` com 1 valor cada? Dependendo do caso, você pode criar um `model` e criar um `ArrayList` do seu tipo.

Você está usando [`toCharArray()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_tochararray.htm), então você quer um array de `char` com a String capturada do banco? Se não, não precisa usar essa função. Quanto ao código, você já tentou algo assim?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    connection = new Conexao().getConnection();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM figura";
    List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> y = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while ( rs.next() ) {
            x.add( rs.getString(2) );
            y.add( rs.getString(3) );
        }

        for (String value : x) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        for (String value : y) {
            System.out.println(y);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: São 2 arrays mesmo, do jeito que tu mostrou passou o valor certinho para o array, eu estou usando o mvc mesmo, esse era só pra testar, no caso eu tentei fazer no model o List<String> x e y, só não entendi como eu chamo ele dentro do while.